# Attribute filter cannot be applied to Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Link_Product_Collection

Tags: magento

When retrieving a related products collection in Magento:

```
 $this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
            ->setPositionOrder()
            ->addStoreFilter()
        ;
```

What would be the method of filtering that collection by a product attribute?

I have tried this in several different ways which i would normally filter collections.  But my understanding of collections must be lacking.

Can someone please advise me on how to filter this collection, for example, say i wanted to filter out a specific product with and sku of "TEST-SKU".

I would normally use `->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('neq' => 'TEST-SKU'))` : but this type of filtering does not work with this collection which is of type: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Link_Product_Collection`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Link_Product_Collection` isn't able to do that. I'd suggest either iterating over all items in the collection (if there isn't too many of them) and filtering them in PHP or extending the collection class and build the funtionality yourself.

Answer (score 1):

try using addFieldToFilter, for example:

```
->addFieldToFilter('sku', array('neq' => 'TEST-SKU'))
```